# How do I sum datetimes without a cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Best practices question. I have a tables with `DATED, AgentName, Available_Time (DATETIME)`. The dates are not sequential, for example missing all weekends, similarly the `AgentName` do not exist in every day.

I am trying to get the `SUM` and `AVG` per user for a given date range. Currently, I have a Cursor that goes through all available dates, inside that is another cursor going through all the names for that date. I had hoped to use `SUM(COLUMN)` but you cannot do that with `DATETIME` you can only do `COLUMN + COLUMN`. I tried converting to `TIME`, which works except once it totals over 24 hours it rolls back to 00:00:000 and I lose time. I was thinking `CTE`, but still can't use `sum`. The code below basically models it, but obviously gives me line not sums. The data set is small so the cursors are not a problem, I just don't like them :). Thoughts?

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RESULTS') is not null
    drop table #RESULTS;

CREATE TABLE #RESULTS (AgentName NVARCHAR(100)
                        ,DATED DATE
                        ,Available_Time DATETIME
                        )

INSERT INTO #RESULTS 
VALUES 
('007','1/1/2018','1900/01/01 02:33:51')
,('007','1/2/2018','1900/01/01 00:32:37')
,('007','1/3/2018','1900/01/01 01:02:54')
,('007','1/4/2018','1900/01/01 01:22:14')
,('007','1/5/2018','1900/01/01 01:48:42')
,('007','1/7/2018','1900/01/01 01:16:07')
,('007','1/9/2018','1900/01/01 02:25:56')
,('007','1/11/2018','1900/01/01 02:00:09')
,('007','1/13/2018','1900/01/01 12:36:01')
,('007','1/15/2018','1900/01/01 11:56:25')
,('K','1/11/2018','1900/01/01 02:00:09')
,('K','1/13/2018','1900/01/01 12:36:01')
,('K','1/15/2018','1900/01/01 11:56:25')

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RESULTS2') is not null
    drop table #RESULTS2;

CREATE TABLE #RESULTS2 (RNUMBER INT
                        ,AgentName NVARCHAR(100)
                        --,DATED DATE
                        ,Available_Time DATETIME
                        )

INSERT INTO #RESULTS2
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AGENTNAME ORDER BY DATED) RNUM
        ,AgentName
        --,DATED
        ,Available_Time
from #RESULTS
;

WITH DATEAGG AS 
(SELECT * 
FROM #RESULTS2
)

SELECT d.AgentName 
        ,d.Available_Time + d2.Available_Time - '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
FROM DATEAGG d
LEFT JOIN DATEAGG d2
on d.AgentName = d2.AgentName
and d.RNUMBER = d2.RNUMBER +1
```

So the final output (this is not correct but) would look something like:

```
Agent  | Total Time 
007    |  1900/01/02 11:54:23 
K      |  1900/01/01 01:54:23
```

From there I can easily DATEDIFF(ss,1900/01/01,RESULT) and get the total times. 
final answer would be something like (depending on how I format)

```
Agent  | Total Time 
007    |  2D 11:54:23 
K      |  0D 01:54:23
```

Comment: So the date and time is the combination of the date field and the datetime field with the date stripped from the latter? You could convert the dates to numbers first. Not sure if that's the ideal way.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to aggregate. Perhaps if you include the code with the cursor you mentioned

Comment: You did a great job posting ddl and sample data. Unfortunately the desired output here is clear as mud. Can you post what you expect as output, and maybe an explanation of the logic to get there?

Comment: Sorry editing for clarity.

Comment: What is your expected OUTCOME for Agent 007?

Comment: Are you allowed to change your table structure?   Because I'm pretty sure you are doing it wrong.   Is `AvailableTime` an actual Time Of Day, or is it an Amount Of Time?  I'm assuming the latter, because the idea of "summing" times of day is silly.

Comment: I can do whatever I want. I chose Date time, so I didn't have roll over issues from Time. I am thinking convert to Seconds as an integer would actually be super easy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTime datatypes are for storing a Point In Time, not an Amount of Time or a duration.   Trying to store a duration (or Amount Of Time) as a Datetime leads to exactly the kind of confusion you are experiencing.

An Amount of time is a number.   The Best Way to store it in your database is to store an integer that contains the lowest subdivision of time that you are interested in measuring.   In your case, it looks like it's seconds.   So instead of storing a DateTime containing "1900/01/01 00:01:00", you should store an integer containing "60".

Then it's easy to SUM, AVG, or do any other math operation you could want, and when it's time to express the result in Days, Hours, Minutes and Seconds, you do the math and string formatting at query time.

Comment: I'm glad you figured this out. For the life of me this made no sense at all. Once you pointed out the duration part it finally clicked.

Comment: I am sure you are correct and this is why even Excel stores everything as an integer, I will be back to mark this correct once I finish. Thanks